# WorkManager Not Returning Result Success

Tags: java, android-workmanager

I am using OneTimeWorkRequest For Downloading Weburls which are loaded in Asset Folder..Inside doWork() I am writing Download Code, Download is enqueued and is completed in a specified directory but after that i don't get the Result Success in Activity where i am using

> getWorkInfoByIdLiveData

My Code Snippet

```
 WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(oneTimeWorkRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@androidx.annotation.Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
         //getting State of WorkInfo
}
});
```

---

```
 @Override
public Result doWork() {
//call for Download URLs
return Result.success(data1);
```

}